# Troubles sharing my project from IntelliJ to GitHub (IntelliJ-GitHub permission denied, error= 13)

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I'm trying to upload my project code from intelliJ to GitHub straight from the intelliJ IDE but I keep getting this annoying error which is as follows:

**Error running Git
Cannot run program "/usr/local/git": error=13, Permission denied**

I fail to understand why, the user I am logged onto has root access so it should be fine, right? (I'm on a mac btw). I have git installed onto the following directory: "/usr/local/git" which is default.

**How do I fix this?** Note that this is my first attempt at using GitHub or Git but I've done plenty of reading before hand and nothing covers this.

Comment: I've also had this error before (but not from intelliJ). Mind trying the first few steps here and report back to verify you're all connected to github already https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just found the fix to this (Mac version anyways not sure about other OS'). The problem seems to be that although on every read me the git installation says it will be in "/usr/local/git" however in IntelliJ you should change that by doing the following:

-Go to preferences --> Version control --> git
-change the directory path for the executable to /usr/local/git/bin/git

I also followed the instructions for setting up the SSH which I was directed towards by the comment above left by "Pippin", (links here:  https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey and https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) although I'm not sure if this was actually a prerequisite for the fix.

Comment: Wow, fixed here. The real is that it was not a permission problem. The error message is the true error.

Comment: Thanks. You saved my day :)